# Inspite of equal ranges - Google sheets error Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size

Tags: excel, google-sheets, countif, sumifs

I am trying to use a Countifs formula with IMPORTRANGE in google sheets

I have used the formula below,

```
=COUNTIFs(IMPORTRANGE("SPREADsheetKEY####","2016 Data!G1:G77"),"Filled and Awaiting",'2016 Deployments'!M1:M77,">"&A4,'2016 Data'!M1:M77,"<"&B4)>
```

Scroll right to see the full formula . Yet I get an error stating - Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size. Is there something wrong with the formula?